# how to count new buyers in table orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i need to count the number of the new buyers in this years ( client who passed order this year and they haven't any order before 2017), how can i do this please

this is my table

```
SLECT TOP 1000 [OrderId]
      ,[clientId]
      ,[TotalAmount]
      ,[DATE]
  FROM [Orders]
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the using `group by` and `having`:

```
select clientid
from orders
group by clientid
having min(orderdate) >= '2017-01-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Close, Gordon :)

To get a count of new buyers, you'd need to do a Count Distinct:

```
select count(distinct clientid)
from orders
having min(orderdate) >= '2017-01-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the total count number of the new buyers in year - 2017

```
Select 
    Count(Distinct ClientID) As [Number of new Buyers]
From Orders
Where DATE >= '2017-01-01';
```